# Symfony 2 and php.yml configuration

Tags: php, symfony, configuration

I was looking for the best place to set up common PHP options in Symfony project and saw a couple of time that *php.yml* is being mentioned - but I found that mostly in v1.x documentation, while in v2.x there is no mention of it (or at least I couldn't find it - Symfony search being down for some time doesn't help neither).

The *php.yml* had nice *'set'*, *'check'* and *'warn'* areas where you could fine tune your configuration.

I tried putting the *php.yml* and setting it up with some options in app/config but it wouldn't work.

Is *php.yml* abandoned in Symfony 2 and if it is - what would be the next best way to nicely set up PHP options?

As requested, here is a simple sample of php.yml I tried, it's very basic:

```
## YAML Template.

set:
    display_errors:     on
    error_log:          phperror.log

check:

warn:
```

*Edit: Additional explanation of why I abandoned solution like Matteo suggested*

> When I did it, something strange was going on. I couldn't pinpoint
>   exactly why, so I left it (I try to avoid all uncertainty when it
>   comes to Symfony because life is so short). 
>   So, I made "*my_own_config.php*" in which I have only a simple line:
>
> ```
> ini_set("error_log", "c:/wamp/logs/phperror2.log");
> ```
>
> In my config_dev.yml, I include it with `- { resource: my_own_config.php }`
>
> In my testing controller, I would print
>
> ```
> echo '<br>'.ini_get('error_log');
> ```
>
> to make sure my settings are really applied & remembered. INITIALLY,
>   when I load the test page for the first time, it would really remember and show the correct new setting, but when I hit F5 after it
>   - it again shows the default, system log. I am running in dev mode all the time. Tried the F5, hard refresh etc, but all of the later calls dropped back
>   down to the default value.
>
> When I'd change *my_own_config.php* file and resave it - again, the first time after that, my custom setting would be
>   remembered, and on following refreshes it goes away.
>   So, I concluded that some weird Symfony caching takes over and overwrites my custom php config file and abandoned that approach.

Comment: For better understanding of your needed configuration, can you post your `php.yml` files?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do some external framework setting change, you can organize your settings as described in the [Miscellaneous Configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html#miscellaneous-configuration), as example, you can put your custom settings in a files like:

```
# app/config/my_settings.php

<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

and include it in your config.yml:

```
# app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: my_settings.php }
```

hope this help

Comment: I actually  did it like that, but that didn't seem right to me. :) I mean - it worked, but putting actual PHP code (init commands) and including it into the config file, somehow seemed wrong. I was expecting that expected would be to include some actual configuration file from the config.yml. I may be wrong with that, it just didnt seem right

Comment: Hi @userfuser I personal agree with you.  This kind of approach is mentioned in the official guide, and i find it useful for some task like [this](http://blog.lavoie.sl/2012/10/automatic-cache-busting-using-git-in-symfony2.html)

Comment: I hear you. BTW, I added some more data (in original question) on why I abandoned that approach. It happened like that in my case, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

php.yml was a Symfony1 config file, it is not suitable for use in Symfony2.

As per the [Symfony Best Practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html) page, the `app/config/config.yml` is suitable for application related settings whilst `app/config/parameters.yml.dist` (from which `parameters.yml` is auto-generated) is suitable for infrastructure related settings.

The standard Symfony2 config files found in app/config are:

- config.yml
- config_dev.yml
- config_prod.yml
- config_test.yml
- parameters.yml (generated from parameters.yml.dist)
- parameters.yml.dist
- routing.yml
- routing_dev.yml
- security.yml
- services.yml

For raw PHP config settings the best place would be the web/app_dev.php (for development) or web/app.php (for production), or system-wide via php.ini. However Symfony has its own PHP error handling service. But you can still turn PHP errors on at the top of the app_dev.php file put - error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Thanks for clearing out the php.yml thing. I'm aware of Symfony's config files (at least those that are clearly mentioned in the docs), but I still don't know how could I add things like:
display_errors: off
to any of those files (except in the way that Matteo proposed and which I tried without success)

Comment: For raw PHP config settings the best place would be the web/app_dev.php (for development) or web/app.php (for production), or system-wide via php.ini. However Symfony has its own PHP error handling service. But you can still turn PHP errors on at the top of the app_dev.php file put - 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: if you could add this last comment of yours (with app_dev.php) as proposed answer, I'd accept it. It's not ideal, but I'll go with that.